# RestSharp, spring boot and JSON.org encoding issue

Tags: java, c#, json, spring

I have one c# desktop client that reads a local DB and uploads the values into the web application.

On the c# side I am using RestSharp and Json.net.

```
private static void DBUpdater()
{
        var client = new RestClient();            
        client.BaseUrl = BASE_URL;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelo.getComunidades(), Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        var request = new RestRequest("/nuevascomunidades", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("comunidades", json);
        Console.WriteLine(client.Execute(request).ResponseStatus);

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I print out by console the generated json string all the characters are well represented.

However, when I get the values from the spring boot/spring data, any special character is represented completely wrong.

On the server side I am deserializing like this usng json.org:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/nuevascomunidades", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void nuevasComunidades(@RequestParam(value = "comunidades") String comunidades) {

    logger.debug("@@@@@@Entra en /nuevascomunidades");
    JSONArray entrada = new JSONArray(comunidades);
    JSONObject aux;
    Comunidad comunidad;
    int top = entrada.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {

        aux = entrada.getJSONObject(i);
        comunidad = new Comunidad(Integer.valueOf(aux.getString("Numero")),
                aux.getString("Nif"),
                aux.getString("Nombre"),
                aux.getString("Direccion"),
                aux.getString("Cod_postal"),
                aux.getString("Poblacion"),
                aux.getString("Provincia"),
                aux.getString("Pais"),
                aux.getBoolean("Baja"));

        comunidadRepositorio.save(comunidad);
        logger.debug("@@@@@@Comunidad añadida: " + comunidad.toString());
    }
}
```

Any idea about how to fix the encoding?

Thanks in advance.

RIGHT REPRESENTATION: "Pais": "ESPAÑA @ ºª ¡¿?!"

WRONG REPRESENTATION:  pais='ESPA├?A @ ┬║┬¬ ┬í┬┐?!'

EDIT:

I just added these settings in the application.properties without any success:

```
# HTTP encoding (HttpEncodingProperties)
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

Comment: You say its being represented completely wrong, can you post an example each of the right representation and the wrong representation that you are seeing?

Comment: I just added the sample strings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the problem.

Basically it was related to the Tomcat 8 settings.
You can read more in here:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3